# If a collapsible element is clicked, collapse all other (collapsible) already opened elements - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working at the moment on my personal website and I have the following issue:

On my website I would like to use a collapsible "main menu" which should acts like the default Bootstrap Accordion. My main navigation menu is an unsorted list, which can collapse. Each `<li>` element has the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute and the nested `<div>` the collapse class. This works fine.

The problem is, that the menu points does not get closed when another menu point is opened. Because of the HTML structure, which I have for design reasons and some other features I need, I am not able to use the Bootstrap default Accordion feature.

In another part on the website I am successfully using already the Accordion feature. There I can have the necessary HTML structure for the Bootstrap Accordion which looks like this (example code from this specific part on my webpage):

```
<div id="cases-list-elements-group" class="**panel-group**">

  <li class="**panel** li-main-style ul-style">

    <a class="nav-scroll list-case-style" href="#case-details-1" 
    data-toggle="collapse" **data-parent="#cases-list-elements-group"**> 
    Case 1 Details </a>

      <div id="case-details-1" class="collapse case-details">
        <div class="container container-cases">
```

The example from above works. So I know how to use the default Accordion from Bootstrap. My problem is, as explained before, I can not have this HTML structure for my main menu:

- *panel-group

  panel

  data-parent="#id-of-the-panel-group"*

So I need a workaround, to close the already opened menu point, after another is expanded. I have searched for hours and found some JavaScript (jQuery) examples which should close the already opened element. Unfortunately no one of the examples I have found helped me to solve my problem. They were not detailed enough for me to understand the logic behind or didn't work at all (yes, didn't worked as well in the provided JS Fiddle examples)

I know I need to do this with some custom JavaScript. After hours of trying I thought, probably someone here can advise.

Answer (score 1):

I know you searched for answers and found some jQuery examples, but have you tried it this way?

Basically what I've done is just hidden a list in each list item. If you intend to make the accordion list items links as well, just add an `href` tag around them. I'm sure this code could be shortened but here's the jQuery half of it:

```
$('#first').hide();
$('#second').hide();
$('#third').hide();
$('#fourth').hide();

$('#colours').click(function(){
    $('#first').slideToggle();
    $('#second:visible').toggle();
    $('#third:visible').toggle();
    $('#fourth:visible').toggle();
})

$('#shapes').click(function(){
    $('#second').slideToggle();
    $('#first:visible').toggle();
    $('#third:visible').toggle();
    $('#fourth:visible').toggle();
})

$('#fruit').click(function(){
    $('#third').slideToggle();
    $('#first:visible').toggle();
    $('#second:visible').toggle();
    $('#fourth:visible').toggle();
})

$('#vehicles').click(function(){
    $('#fourth').slideToggle();
    $('#first:visible').toggle();
    $('#second:visible').toggle();
    $('#third:visible').toggle();
})
```

And here's the full thing **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/RArnone/n8u7mvx0/1/)**