# Bootstrap collapseable menu closing all other submenus when opening one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am coding a side menu with Bootstrap and I am already on quite a good stage. The submenus are opening.
**My problem:** If I click on one submenu it shows the sub links but when opening a second one it doesn't open that links. So I searched for a solution and found this one: [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357073/if-a-collapsible-element-is-clicked-collapse-all-other-collapsible-already-op). I adjusted the code and the javascript file to the changes. Now when opening the menu on my localhost installation, it lags a bit when opening or closing but it is closing all others which are opened. So I thought of asking if anyone here has a better solution or an idea why it lags that much. The code is very long so I will just post a `JSfiddle`: [klick here](https://jsfiddle.net/dcd6oaqr/).

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery doc:

> [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/): default duration 400 milliseconds
>
> [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/): default duration 400 milliseconds

Those are your issues. In any case you can always use [boostrap collapse methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods).

```js
//
// for each collapseable element, except the first, collapse (hide)
//
$('#side-menu ul.collapseable:visible:not(:first)').collapse('hide');

//
// clicking on the collapse anchor:
// get the css selector for the collapsible element
// collapse to hide all except the current one
// collapse to show the current one
//
$('#side-menu a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var ulId = this.getAttribute('href');
    $('#side-menu ul.collapseable').not(ulId).collapse('hide');
    $(ulId).collapse('show');
});
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: "open sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    color: #5e6062;
    height: 100%;
}

/*-------------*/
/*Sidebar Menue*/
/*-------------*/

#side-menu {
    background-color: #323232;
    padding: 0px;
}

#side-menu h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#side-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#side-menu a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
}

#side-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #474747;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}

#side-menu .active a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #474747;
}

#side-menu .settings-btn {
    background-color: #778b1c;
}

#side-menu .settings-btn a {
    color: #fff;
}

#side-menu .settings-btn a:hover {
    background-color: #778b1c;
}

#side-menu .collapseable li {
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 12px;
}

#side-menu .collapseable a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block
}

#side-menu .collapseable a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

/*ALTIS Side-Menü linker Rand*/
#side-menu .collapseable-ALTIS {
    border-left: 4px solid #ffb700;
}

#side-menu .collapseable-ALTIS .active {
    background-color: #474747;
}

#side-menu .collapseable-ALTIS .link:hover {
    background-color: #474747;
}

/*---------------------------*/

/*TANOA Side-Menü linker Rand*/
#side-menu .collapseable-TANOA {
    border-left: 4px solid #00aa1a;
}

#side-menu .collapseable-TANOA .active {
    background-color: #474747;
}

#side-menu .collapseable-TANOA .link:hover {
    background-color: #474747;
}

/*---------------------------*/

/*--------------------*/
/*Main Content Bereich*/
/*--------------------*/

.display-table {
    display: table;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.display-table-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}

.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
}

/*----------------*/
/*Top Menue Leiste*/
/*----------------*/

#nav-header {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7eaec;
}

#nav-header ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    color: #676a6c;
}

#nav-header ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 17px 0px;
}

#nav-header ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-header .logout {
    color: #676a6c;
}

#nav-header .logout:hover {
    color: #676a6c;
}

#nav-header #welcome {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

/*-----------------------*/
/*Mobile Menu Toggle Icon*/
/*-----------------------*/

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #778b1c;
    background-color: #778b1c;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #778b1c;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #778b1c;
}

.navbar-default .icon-bar {
    border: 1px white solid;
}

/*------*/
/*Inhalt*/
/*------*/

#content header {
    border-bottom: 1px #f3f3f4 solid;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

#content {
    margin: 20px 0px 50px 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 4px #778b1c solid;
}

.content-ALTIS {
    border-top: 4px #ffb700 solid !important;
}

.page_title {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.content-inner {
    padding: 20px;
}

.content-inner a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #2b5f8b;
}

.valign-top {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.valign-center {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.horizontal-middle {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<main class="container-fluid display-table">

    <!-- Menu -->
    <div class="col-lg-2 c display-table-cell valign-top" id="side-menu">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <ul>
            <!-- Startseite -->
            <li class="link active">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Text 1
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- ALTIS Dropdown Menu -->
            <li class="link">
                <a href="#collapse-ALTIS" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="collapse-ALTIS" id="ALTIS"
                   href="#collapse-ALTIS"  aria-expanded="true">
                    Text 2
                </a>
                <ul class="collapseable collapseable-ALTIS collapse in" id="collapse-ALTIS" aria-expanded="true">
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-users hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-exclamation-triangle hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- TANOA Dropdown Menu -->
            <li class="link">
                <a href="#collapse-TANOA" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="collapse-TANOA" id="TANOA">
                    Text 3
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse collapseable collapseable-TANOA" id="collapse-TANOA">
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-users hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-exclamation-triangle hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- KOTH Dropdown Menu -->
            <li class="link">
                <a href="#collapse-KOTH" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="collapse-KOTH" id="KOTH">
                    Text 4
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse collapseable collapseable-KOTH" id="collapse-KOTH">
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-users hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-exclamation-triangle hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- TOOLS Dropdown Menu -->
            <li class="link">
                <a href="#collapse-TOOLS" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="collapse-TOOLS" ID="TOOLS">
                    Text 5
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse collapseable collapseable-TOOLS" id="collapse-TOOLS">
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- FILTER Dropdown Menu -->
            <li class="link">
                <a href="#collapse-FILTER" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="collapse-FILTER" id="FILTER">
                    Text 6
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse collapseable collapseable-FILTER" id="collapse-FILTER">
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-globe hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-shield hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-address-book hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-database hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- Einstellungen -->
            <li class="link settings-btn">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Text 7
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <section class="col-md-10 col-sm-11 display-table-cell valign-top">
        <!-- vertikales Menu -->
        <aside class="row">
            <header id="nav-header" class="clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <nav class="navbar-default pull-left">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="offcanvas"
                                data-target="#side-menu">
                            <span class="sr-only">Navigation aufklappen und zuklappen</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <!-- Menu oben rechts -->
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <ul class="pull-right">
                        <li id="welcome" class="hidden-xs">Welcome</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="logout">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </header>
        </aside>

        <!-- Seiteninhalt -->
        <div id="content">
            <header>
                <h2 class="page_title">Title</h2>
            </header>

            <div class="content-inner">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works very well, but can you maybe explain, how this Javascript code works? And how do I have to deal, when I want one to be opened at the beginning with the `in`class? Afterwards it should close when another submenu is getting closed? Thanks a lot

Comment: @DerLauskop Snippet updated: added comments and in and aria-expanded to the first collapse element. Please take a look to the documentation reported in the answer.